# Pass SQL array through Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I currently am trying the following code:

```
 $sql = $db->query("select id,username,fullname from userss ORDER BY fullname ASC");
        while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
            $username[] = $row['username'];
        }
        $form = new Zend_Form();
        $form->setAction('/index/change')
             ->setMethod('post');

        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('foo', array(
            'multiOptions' => array(
                $username,
                )));
        $form->addElement($element);
        echo $form;
```

The desired result is the `<select>` form showing the elements `<option value='username'>Full Name</option>` where username is `username` from SQL and Full Name is `fullname` from sql.

Right now, it shows `<option value='0'>Full Name</option>`

I'm not quite sure how to specify the first part of the array, so that it will essentially be username => Full Name

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the value of an option in a `Zend_Form_Element_Select`, the array key defines the value, and the array value defines the text in the select that the user sees.

Try this:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('foo', array(
    'multiOptions' => array(
        $username  => $fullname,
        $username2 => $fullname2,
)));
```

You were seeing 0 since the array didn't have string keys, it defaulted to use the numerically indexed array keys as values.

Given your code, you would do this:

```
$username = array();

while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $username[$row['username']] = $row['fullname'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm giving this a shot, but a bit confused what you meant in the first bit of code.  Where did variables $fullname and $username2 and $fullname2 come from? The only variable I have is $username as defined in the while loop.

Comment: It was just an example of what the array might look like if you had multiple items (setting key => value pairs for the select box).  You can just replace your loop with the one I posted and keep `'multiOptions' => array($username)` as is; or use beginner's answer as fetchPairs is a good solution as well if you don't need the user id for anything.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. The issue was actually that I simplified my query in this post (fullname isn't an actual column...I needed to concat two tables...and thus the $username variable was still getting a 0)

Answer (score 2):

To make populating select element easier ZF provides fetchPairs

```
     $sql = "select username,fullname from userss ORDER BY fullname ASC";
      $db =  Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
     $select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('foo');
     $select->setMultiOptions($db->fetchPairs($sql));
```

This way saves you from iterating data (for, while loops) yourself.